# Multiple edit in UITableView.... 

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I would like to add a UIBarButtonItem which is titled "edit", when I click the "edit", I can select the row to delete. Is there any simple solution on Apple API already? or I need to customize made the UITableView and the action myself? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options :

1. Customize it like you said
2. Add a `UINavigationBar` and use `UIVavigationItem` , and then use `self.editbuttonitem -> read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationBar)

Comment: But how can I implement the multiple delete action?
I can detect the UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete, but it only detect one only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The table view come pre- configured with the ability to delete cell when you enter edit mode. Is there something unique that you're trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you subclassing `UITableViewController`? If so:

You need to add an edit button somewhere, like the navigation bar:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    ...
}
```

And add this function to your view controller:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated]; // must be called first according to Apple docs

    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

You probably also want to set the editing style for the table row:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.editing)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    else
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
}
```